# I am trying to run a cjsx file. and while running "bundle install" i got this error.

Tags: javascript, ruby, terminal, rubygems, reactjs

Gorans-MacBook-Pro:Dweller Goran$ bundle install
.
.
.
.
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.3'` succeeds before bundling